# Unable to change visibility of Panel in rendered HTML code

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an aspx page (say MyPage.aspx) where a part of it has the following structure -

```
<asp:DataList ... >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        ...
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="table" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow ... >
                <asp:TableCell ... >
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnToggle" OnClick="ToggleVisibility" ... >
                </asp:TableCell>
                ...
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:DataGrid ... >
        </asp:DataGrid>
        <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server" ...>
            <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" ...>
            <asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" ...>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        ...
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

What I am trying to do is that whenever `btnToggle` is clicked, it toggles visibility of `panel`. I'm getting the `panel` in `ToggleVisibility()` like this -

```
Dim panelToggle As Panel = sender.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Controls(5)
```

In this function I'm able to change its `Visible` property, but its visibility doesn't change on the rendered HTML page (checking through browser).

I'm unable to figure out why is that. Kindly, help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `OnItemCommand` event to the DataList that handles the button click. You don't need to add the `OnClick` event to the button itself anymore.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnToggle" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
            Panel content.
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Then in code behind

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //find the panel in the datalist item object and cast it back to a panel
    Panel panel = e.Item.FindControl("panel") as Panel;

    //you can now access it's properties
    panel.Visible = false;
}
```

VB

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As DataListCommandEventArgs)
    'find the panel in the datalist item object and cast it back to a panel
    Dim panel As Panel = CType(e.Item.FindControl("panel"),Panel)

    'you can now access it's properties
    panel.Visible = false
End Sub
```

Comment: Though the problem was with the logic I had written to `ToggleVisibility()`, I used your idea to manage that better. Actually, I was trying to set the visibility of the buttons first & if any one was going to be visible, I had to set that `panel` visible but since, by default, the `panel` was invisible (`Visible="false"`), the program wasn't allowing me to make those button's visible first without first setting that `panel` visible.